# Office Communicator 2007 Nicknames

Tags: windows, office-communicator-2007

How can I can assign nicknames to my contacts in Office Communicator 2007 R2?

When I right click on a contact, the Properties option is disabled.  Is this due to some policy setting or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Properties` option is greyed out, the administrator must have disabled it. Even if you could open the `Properties`, you probably won't be able to change the `Display Name` as the administrator may have locked them as well.

We use Office Communicator 2007 R2 in our company and when I right click on a contact and select the `Properties`, the relevant window is opened but I cannot change any of the entries. They are fetched from the address book in our Exchange Server, and we have no rights to change them.